# How to show non consecutive dates in Fullcalendar Timegrid view?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have successfully implemented fullcalendar with Timegrid View in my react project.

I'm now trying to show non-consecutive dates.
By default, it's possible to show custom consecutive dates either by [range](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/visibleRange) or by [duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/duration).

Right now, I'm thinking of showing the full range between my earliest and latest date, and inject a class to the column elements and hide them with `display: none`. (which I realize is far from being optimal)

As there's nothing built-in for my use case, what would be the best way to achieve this?
Is there a way to filter dates before they are rendered?

Note: there's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298319/fullcalendar-1-day-vertical-resource-view-only-show-specific-individual-date) which doesn't address mine.

Comment: You'd probably have to build a [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) by cloning the timegrid view and then altering it, but I suspect it wouldn't be easy. Consider carefully whether this requirement is 100% necessary or not before you spend the time on it.

Comment: @ADyson I elected again created a custom view for that reason.I have found another solution by altering the DOM when dates are rendered. ([See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194199/how-to-show-non-consecutive-dates-in-fullcalendar-timegrid-view/62212005#62212005))

If you see something to improve, I welcome any feedback.

Comment: Ok I didn't realise you were using fullCalendar 5, as it's not fully released yet. That would have been a useful thing to mention originally. It does give you more flexibility over the appearance of the calendar, as you've now discovered yourself.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include I'm using Fullcalendar 5.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using the [Day-Header](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/day-header-render-hooks) and [Day-Cell](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/day-cell-render-hooks) Render Hooks. (available from FullCalendar 5)

---

1. First, I set the range rendered from the earliest date to the latest date by adding `visibleRange` props to the FullCalendar:

```
visibleRange={{
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate,
            }}
```

*Note: `endDate` is exclusive.*

2. I then created an array with all event dates.

```
const eventDatesList = [];
    events.forEach((event) => {
        eventDatesList.push(event.start);
    });
```

3. Finally, I created a callback `handleDayDidMount`, which will run each time a Day-Header and a Day-Cell render and added to the Day-Header and Day-Cell corresponding props:

```
dayCellDidMount={(arg => handleDayDidMount(arg))}
dayHeaderDidMount={(arg => handleDayDidMount(arg))}
```

*Note: The same callback can be used for both props.*

If the date rendered is not in our date list, we remove the corresponding element from the dom.

```
const handleDayDidMount = ({date, el}) => {
        let currentDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(date).toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
        if (!eventDatesList.includes(currentDate)) {
            el.remove()
        }
    }
```

---

4. The only issue remaining is cosmetic: the width for all the days is still rendered.

To solve that, we can use the `viewDidMount` props and use a callback to dynamically change the DOM elements controlling the width.

```
viewDidMount={(arg) => handleMount(arg)}
```

The elements are `div.fc-timegrid-body` and `div.fc-timegrid-slots table`, so in the callback I have the following:

```
const handleMount = ({ el }) => {
        // Adapt column width to number of dates present
        const timegridBody = el.querySelectorAll('div.fc-timegrid-body');
        const timegridSlots = el.querySelectorAll(
            'div.fc-timegrid-slots table',
        );

        // Update width based on rendered dates number
        let newWidth = eventDatesList.length * dayMinWidth;

        timegridBody[0].style['min-width'] = `${newWidth}px`;
        timegridSlots[0].style['min-width'] = `${newWidth}px`;
    };
```

*Note: `dayMinWidth` is a variable set as [day props](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/dayMinWidth).*

Et voilà!

If I change my approach in the future, I'll update this answer.